Stress at the end of verses
In Стихи к Пушкину by Marina Tsvetaeva we have:

Кого ж это так — точно воры вора́
Пристреленного — выносили?
Изменника? Нет. С проходного двора —
Умнейшего мужа России.

According to Викисловарь, we should have во́ра and not вора́; it seems that, since we have двора́, the author wanted to have rhymes and just modified the stress of the word in a way that was convenient to her and indicated it to the reader. I find it surprising. Is my interpretation correct and is it a phenomenon that appears in other poems?
Now, here is another case, which is related but slightly different. In Поэма заставы by the same author we have

Здесь платят! Здесь Богом и Чёртом,
Горбом и торбой!
Здесь молодости как над мёртвым
Поют над собой.

Looking at other stanzas I find it weird to have то́рбой and собо́й. I am inclined to read торбо́й, but objectively I should read то́рбой (the author could have written explicitly торбо́й like she did with вора́ if she wanted to modify the stress). I was not able to find this poem recited in some video; I would like to know how a native Russian speaker would read it.

https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/variativnost-udareniya-v-russkoi-poezii


Is my interpretation correct and is it a phenomenon that appears in other poems?

Stress in modern Russian is subject to changes that are happening, by linguistic measures, very fast. A stress pattern for a word, and even a whole class of words, can change within a single generation.
One such stress pattern, probably the best known one, is that of the plural of some masculine words like торт, порт, мост etc. which is shifting from 1a (то́рты) to 1c (торты́). There are also many other ad-hoc examples: жемчуг, воздух, перепел and so on.
In Old Russian, the accent patterns were subject to somewhat complex, yet strict rules (described in great detail in Zaliznyak's От праславянской акцентуации к русской). Each morpheme (a root, a prefix or preposition, a suffix, and a declensional ending) was a part of one of three classes, and the combination of these classes within a single phonetic word would define the stress of the whole word.
In modern Russian, these rules don't function any longer, but their former existence is still traceable in a certain sense. Some classes of words allow shifting their stress in a way that feels natural and doesn't go against the grain, while others don't.
Many Russian-speaking kids have trouble accepting the stress in за автобу́сом автобу́с in Marshak's Почта, because shifting the stress in this particular word is stretching the poetic license too thin.
On the other hand, воры belongs to the class of words that does allow shifting the stress in the plural nominative and in the singular genitive, because there exist many other monosyllabic words ending in a consonant, that do the exact same thing seemingly arbitrarily.
In the words that do allow it, the stress of a single word can naturally shift even within a single poem, sometimes even as a deliberate word play:


А если вы споёте, а может быть, залаете,
А может, замычите (коровы ведь мычат), –
То вам седло большое, ковёр и телевизор
В подарок сразу вру́чат, а может быть, вруча́т.




Я все награды роздал, я все чины раздал.
Я сам всё это со́здал, я сам это всё созда́л.




I am inclined to read торбо́й, but objectively I should read то́рбой (the author could have written explicitly торбо́й like she did with вора́ if she wanted to modify the stress).

The non-standard reading торбо́й is exactly how you should read it, because the meter of this part of the poem is the amphibrach.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You say "According to Викисловарь, we should have во́ра and not вора́". The phrase "should have" isn't really relevant to linguistics. Should have - says who? The English Wiktionary shows there is a variant declension of вор with ending stress, e.g. in the accusative and genitive singular, like вора́, although it states it is uncommon and non-standard. In fact, Avanesov shows such stress in вор у вора́ дубинку украл ("there is no honour among thieves", literally a thief has stolen a club from another thief). In English, there is a phrase "poetic licence" (поэтическая вольность). It is strictly speaking acceptable for poets to use language they way they wish to. I'm sure a native speaker will give a proper response before long.

Removing the two first sentences and the second to last one of this answer, this answer is very good (still it is very useful): I did not know other uses of вора́ and I understand now why M. T. allowed herself to use вора́ (it is not something she would do it with any word). "says who?" > I gave my source. "The phrase "should have" isn't really relevant to linguistics. " > If I say "Я идёшь" or 'Я и́ду", my teacher will tell me "you should say Я иду́ and she will be right".

The first two sentences were the most important ones in my answer. It is a fundamental misunderstanding of linguistics to think prescriptive forms are the only correct ones. In the West, at least, if you turn up to your PhD viva voce spouting prescriptivism, you don't get your PhD. It is no longer academically accepted. What is accepted is that there are registers of language: R1 - colloquial speech; R2 - neutral style; R3 - poetry, elevated or high style. The correct register for the correct occasion is preferred, but none is "incorrect".
